# Is there a way to display button in the angular ui-grid on mouseover on that particular row?

Tags: angularjs, mouseover, angular-ui-grid

I have buttons in my angularjs ui-grid.But, those must be displayed only on mouseover on that particular row.I tried many things with cell template.But, not successful in doing it. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a rowTemplate and have ng-mouseenter="**grid.appScope.rowHover(row)**" in the template. So is mouseleave

here is code:

```
    $scope.gridOptions.gridOptions: {        
       rowTemplate: ' <div ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ui-grid-cell ng-mouseenter="**grid.appScope.rowHover(row)**" ></div>',        

    columnDefs: [ 
      { field: 'status', displayName: 'Status', width: 80 },
      { field: 'to.name', displayName: 'Assignee', width: 200 }   
    ]           
}

      $scope.gridOptions.appScopeProvider= {
   rowHover: function(row) {
    $scope.row= row.entity;      
    }
```

};